# Java generic array

Tags: java

I am trying too create a generic class, called box, with a type parameter that simulates drawing an item at random out of a box. For example, the box might contain Strings representing names, or it might contain integers representing a random drawing for a lottery. It has a few methods, which I know how to do, but I'm not sure how to create the box using an array.

Comment: What language are you using? Your title says "Javascript" but your tag says "Java". Java is to Javascript like Ham is to Hamster. They only share a few letters in their name.

Comment: Please edit the question tags, citing some other StackOverflow user. Java to JavaScript is same as pain to painting.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution!

```
class Box {
  constructor(choices) {
    this.choices = choices;
  }
  randomSelection() {
    return this.choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.choices.length)];
  }
}
let bag = [
  "whiskey",
  "laptop",
  "chewing gum",
  "pencils",
  "notebook",
  "dental floss",
  "1% milk"
];
let result = new Box(bag).randomSelection();

console.log(result);
```

You create a simple class with a parameter. The function `randomSelection()` I made randomly selects an array value and returns it. You plug an array in and call the function with the class instance and voila----it randomly selects a value from your array every time you call it!

You can customize this class of course to your liking/needs.